# textbox search mysql code does not work

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I make a code to search some data to database mysql using vb.net language, I think there is no error in my code but the code does not work

This is my code in the textbox

```
Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("patientName Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
```

This is the error message when I type in my texbox search

Comment: Welkom to Stackoverflow, Stackoverflow is not a site where questions can be asked like "Why is this code not working?" without Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.. please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your column name has a space in. You need to provide the name in quotes or backticks (not sure which)

Comment: And you left out the error message.